# Irb Error: undefined method 'split'

Tags: ruby, interpreter, irb, pry

I recently opened up irb, and now all of a sudden every time I run irb it gives me this error:

```
load error: /Users/addisonbean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
/Users/addisonbean/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/addisonbean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/addisonbean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/addisonbean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/addisonbean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:236:in `load'
/Users/addisonbean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:236:in `run_config'
/Users/addisonbean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:19:in `setup'
irb(main):001:0>
```

But as I've shown you it still gives me the prompt after all the errors

This is all the code inside of /Users/addisonbean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc (the numbers are line numbers)

```
8  if ENV["rvm_path"].nil?
9    require File.join(ENV["HOME"], "irbrc")
10 else
11   require File.join(ENV["rvm_path"], "scripts", "irbrc")
12 end
```

And I have no ~/.irbrcw

I would love some help on this, thanks!

Comment: Your error message indicates that `/Users/addisonbean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc` has at least eleven lines, which contradicts with what you wrote about that file.

Comment: Ya, sorry there are comments in it, I will add those in for the line numbering

Comment: Installing Pry _after_ this error fixes this error... I don't know if removing Pry and reinstalling Pry has the same effect. And the IRB prompt looks different after installing Pry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [line 45 of rvm's `scripts/irbrc.rb`](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/irbrc.rb#L40-L49), we can find that `split` being called on `path`. It would seem that for some reason, your `path` is `nil` - probably because one of those `rescue nil` blocks is running.

I wouldn't advise hacking around the internals of rvm, but it looks like you can fake this by setting the environment variable `$rvm_ruby_string`, as `irbrc.rb` checks that before it tries to figure it out. Setting it to "2.1.2" should match what it calculates.

Comment: Never mind, I uninstalled 2 pry-related gems and now pry runs fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These steps solved my problem:

- find the current ruby version

> ruby -v

example:

> ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

- remove this version

> rvm remove 2.1.2

- install again

> rvm install 2.1.2

Comment: Thanks, but I had to reformat my hard drive (not because of this) so that ended up fixing it.